# c3.js. Creating graphs within a loop to multiple divs with the same class/ID?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

My code:

```
c3.generate({
  bindto: $( ".budget-donut-chart" ),
  data: {
    columns: [
        ['Budget Used', budgetUsed],
        ['Budget Remaining', budgetRemaining],
    ],
    type : 'donut',
  },
  legend: {
      show: false
  },
  color: {
      pattern: ["#EE543A", "#a2d47f"]
  },
  donut: {
      title:  '$' + budgetRemaining + ' remaining'
  }
});
```

Currently, the ".budget-donut-chart" div is in a each loop and my code only displays the chart for the first div. I want it to display on every div contained within the loop. Any ideas on how I would do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `bindto: $( ".budget-donut-chart" ),` to `bindto: $( "#budget-donut-chart"+index ),`

Change your id for the div to `id="budget-donut-chart"+index`.

Pass your index to the function drawing the chart.

Where index is the index of the record in the loop.